# Выполнение всех функций на странице по очереди нажатием одной кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Как сделать чтобы функции выполнялись поочередно нажимая на одну кнопку? (перед этим данные в формы вводятся самостоятельно). (Лишнее пока удалил из js чтобы минимизировать код).

```js
let resultF3;
let resultF4;
let resultF5;
let resultF6;


function breakWay2() {
    const form = document.querySelector('#formInput2');
    //const va = +form[0].value;
    resultF3 = 38.5 / (3.6 * 6.9);
    console.log(+resultF3.toFixed(4));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF3');
    result.innerText = `Результат: ${Number(resultF3.toFixed(4))}`;
    return +resultF3.toFixed(4);

}

function breakWay3() {
    const form = document.querySelector('#formInput3');
    const Sj = +form[0].value;   
    const L = +form[1].value;
    const C = +form[2].value;
    //const t3 = Number(document.querySelector('#T33').value);
    resultF4 = Sj + 38.5 * 0.25 / 7.2 - L - C;
    console.log(+resultF4.toFixed(2));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF4');
    result.innerText = `Результат: ${Number(resultF4.toFixed(2))}`;
    return +resultF4.toFixed(2);

}

function breakWay4() {       
  resultF5 = resultF3 - (Math.sqrt(resultF3 ** 2 - (2 * resultF4) / 6.9 + (0.25 * 0.25) / 4));
  console.log(+resultF5.toFixed(4));
  const result = document.querySelector('#resultF5');
  result.innerText = `Результат: ${Number(resultF5.toFixed(4))}`;
  return +resultF5.toFixed(4); 
}


function breakWay5() {
    const form = document.querySelector('#formInput6');  
    resultF6 = (1.91 - resultF5) * (38.5 /3.6) + resultF4;
    console.log(+resultF6.toFixed(3));
    const result = document.querySelector('#resultF6');
    result.innerText = `Результат: ${Number(resultF6.toFixed(3))}`;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formula 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>При торможении</h1>

<h1>Значение Tt</h1>
<form id="formInput2">
<div>
        <label>va</label>
        <input type="number" value = 38.5>
    </div>
</form>
<button onclick="breakWay2()">Результат V</button>
<h2 id="resultF3"></h2>

<h1>Значение Sтд</h1>
<form id="formInput3">
<div>
        <label>va</label>
        <input type="number" value = 38.5>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Sj</label>
        <input type="number" value = 9.3>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>L</label>
        <input type="number" value = 2.52>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>C</label>
        <input type="number" value = 0.838>
    </div>
</form>
<button onclick="breakWay3()">Результат Sтд</button>
<h2 id="resultF4"></h2>

<h1>Значение Tt1</h1>
<form id="formInput5">
    
</form>
<button onclick="breakWay4()">Результат Tt1</button>
<h2 id="resultF5"></h2>

<h1>Значение Sa</h1>
<form id="formInput6">
    

</form>
<button onclick="breakWay5()">Результат Sa</button>
<h2 id="resultF6"></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `function startAll() { breakWay2(); breakWay3(); breakWay4(); breakWay5(); }`

Comment: @SwaD, спасибо большое за помощь, работает)